# Python: Unable to install pandas_profiling

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried installing profiling pandas profiling library with the following command from the terminal:

```
conda install pandas-profiling
```

Output:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_profiling'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61396448/4549682

`conda install -c conda-forge pandas-profiling=2.6.0`

where 2.6.0 should be replaced with the latest version as shown here: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pandas-profiling

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
pip install pandas-profiling
```

or:

```
conda install -c anaconda pandas-profiling
```

Comment: The anaconda channel is a much older version of pandas_profiling which you probably don't want.